# Selecting Polygon Feature using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, select

I used ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.25 for developing.  I want to select polygons within 1km radius. so I used a sample code that esri provides. But it works only for point features. I want to use that code for select polygons.

Can you help me to correct my coding?

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://203.189.68.219:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Sites/inginimitiya_Tank/MapServer/11"
/*
  ,{
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    infoTemplate: template,
    outFields: ["Name", "OBJECTID"]
  }
*/
);

var symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(
  SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
  12,
  new SimpleLineSymbol(
    SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new Color([247, 34, 101, 0.9]),
    1
  ),
  new Color([207, 34, 171, 0.5])
);
featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(symbol);

// Make unselected features invisible
//var nullSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(0);
//featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(nullSymbol));

map.addLayer(featureLayer);
var circleSymb = new SimpleFillSymbol(
  SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
  new SimpleLineSymbol(
    SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SHORTDASHDOTDOT,
    new Color([105, 105, 105]),
    2
  ), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25])
);
var circle;

// When the map is clicked create a buffer around the click point of the specified distance
map.on("click", function (evt) {
  circle = new Circle({
    center: evt.mapPoint,
    geodesic: true,
    radius: 1,
    radiusUnit: "esriMiles"
  });
  map.graphics.clear();
  var graphic = new Graphic(circle, circleSymb);
  map.graphics.add(graphic);

  var query = new Query();
  query.geometry = circle.getExtent();
  // Use a fast bounding box query. It will only go to the server if bounding box is outside of the visible map.
  featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, selectInBuffer);
});

function selectInBuffer(response) {
  var feature;
  var features = response.features;
  var inBuffer = [];
  // Filter out features that are not actually in buffer, since we got all points in the buffer's bounding box
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    feature = features[i];
    if (circle.contains(feature.geometry)) {
      inBuffer.push(feature.attributes[featureLayer.objectIdField]);
    }
  }
  var query = new Query();
  query.objectIds = inBuffer;
  // Use an objectIds selection query (should not need to go to the server)
  featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (results) {
    var totalPopulation = sumPopulation(results);
    var r = "";
    r = "<b>The total Census Block population within the buffer is <i>" + totalPopulation + "</i>.</b>";
    dom.byId("messages").innerHTML = r;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace most of the `selectInBuffer` function, by performing a spatial operation on the `query`. Notice, i also perform a `featureLayer.queryIds`

```
map.on("click", function(evt){
  circle = new Circle({
    center: evt.mapPoint,

  ...

  var query = new Query();
  query.geometry = circle;
  query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
  featureLayer.queryIds(query, selectInBuffer);
});
```

Now you have the objectids of the geometries that intersect the 1 km circle :

```
function selectInBuffer(inBuffer) {
  /*
  var features = response.features;
  var inBuffer = [];
  // Filter out features that are not actually in buffer, since we got all points in the buffer's bounding box
  for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    var feature = features[i];
    if(circle.contains(feature.geometry)){
      inBuffer.push(feature.attributes[featureLayer.objectIdField]);
    }
  }
  */
  var query = new Query();
  query.objectIds = inBuffer;

  ...
```

Oh, by the way, you specified 1 **esriMiles**, not kilometer. You can fix this, using the module `"esri/units"` and add this line in the creation of the circle `radiusUnit: units.KILOMETERS,`